# Connecting android to mysql database using php : Multiple user support?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to develop an android application. In the application the user can search some data from the database that is on the server side. For that, I use a php script that is on the server side along with mysql database. I give it a call from the android app and the php code connects with the database and returns a json result which I decode and use it as I want.

My question is this. Can this support multiple users at the same time? For example 2 different users use at the same time the search function for retrieving data from the database. I know that the database itself can handle this kind of requests, but what about the php service?

Here is an example of the php code:

```
<?php
     mysql_connect("host","username","password");
     mysql_select_db("Deal");
     $sql=mysql_query("select * from CITY where CITY_NAME like 'A%'");

     while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
       $output[]=$row;

     print(json_encode($output));
     mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP script is being launched by web-server environment. It's hard to imagine there exists web-server that doesn't support multi-threading at present. So, don't worry. The answer is positive.

Comment: Well you are probably right. I found the code from [Here](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/#comment-10195). It is specifically for android OS and it wouldn't make much sense if it didn't support multiple users. My further question is how is that possible?

Comment: This (and other) php script doesn't relate to android OS, forget about it. This code runs not on android device but on server side. there can be probably apache web server installed under which all php scripts run.